# Omission of `self` with accessors

Tags: ruby, self, accessor

When accessing an instance variable via accessor method `attribute`, what is the difference between the expressions `self.attribute` and `attribute`? Say,  we define an accessor:

```
def post
  @post
end
```

We can call

```
self.post
```

or simply

```
post
```

What is special about adding `self`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes a difference when there might be a local var that shadows method call. Using `self` allows us to specify that we want the method, not the local var. See an example:

```
class Foo
  def post
    @post
  end

  def post= (content)
    @post = content
  end 

  def test
    #difference 1 
    p post # >> nil

    @post = 10
    p post # >> 10

    post = 42
    p post # >> 42
    p self.post # >> 10

    #difference 2
    # assign to @post, note that you can put space between "self.post" and "="
    self.post = 12 

    #otherwise it means assigning to a local variable called post.
    post = 12
  end
end

Foo.new.test
```

Comment: Hi, I have added something to the example code. I think it can be the reason why the self keyword is especially preferred for attributes

Comment: @GingerJim: yes, that too. But I thought you were asking only about getters.

Comment: Are you sure about the difference when you put spaces around `=`? I don't think it makes difference, and in both cases without the receiver, it is an assignment to a local variable.

Comment: The ambiguity between local variable references and getter methods arises for receiverless argumentless message sends. The other way to avoid this ambiguity is to add an empty argument list, so `post()` will also call the getter, just like `self.post` does. The latter is more idiomatic, but it won't work for private methods, because those can only be called without an explicit receiver.

Comment: @sawa: Yeah, sorry, should have read more carefully what I approve.